# Switch to certain Browser/Document Mode for certain Bookmark

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, shortcuts, bookmarks

Is there any way to tell Internet Explorer 11 to use a certain [Document/Browser mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a certain Bookmark/URL?

Alternatively, is it possible to make a shortcut that points to the website like so:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.myurl.com
```

With additional parameters which triggers the desired mode?

A scripting solution would be fine, but a separate search turned up not much at all.

Comment: Just for clarification: It's not enough to just add that specific URL to the [compatibility view list](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11) which views the site as in IE7? You also want to choose [IE8, IE9 or IE10](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn321432.aspx)?

Comment: That never occurred to me.  Yes, I think that *may* be enough for *this specific case*, but I think I'd like to let the question stand for the case of having to specify any browser (the site in question, irritatingly enough, checks the UAS against IE8's string specifically and bars **all** other access).